# Turn stringified tree into a list of directories (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, tree, lex

I am in need of building a function that can transform a string (which includes information about a tree structure of file directories) into a list (array) of separated directories. Example below:

**[EXAMPLE INPUT] This is an example string that carries an encrypted information about the tree-like structure of directories:**

```
"bucket[f1[a&b&f[]&ff1[a&b]]&f2[a&b&ff1[a&b]]&f3[ff1[a]]]"
```

Brackets `[]` are appearing only after folder name and show the range of the folder (empty ones mean an empty folder). All items are separated by `&`.

**[EXPECTED OUTPUT] And this is what the output should look like given the example input:**

```
[ '/bucket/f1/a',
  '/bucket/f1/b',
  '/bucket/f1/f/',   // <- directory to folder
  '/bucket/f1/ff1/a',
  '/bucket/f1/ff1/b',
  '/bucket/f2/a',
  '/bucket/f2/b',
  '/bucket/f2/ff1/a',
  '/bucket/f2/ff1/b',
  '/bucket/f3/ff1/a' ]
```

I have tried an recursive algorithm that uses string splits and regex to get the content of the brackets but I failed to distinguish the `&` on different "directory depths" using regex.

Comment: Why is `/bucket/f1/b` missing the trailing slash whereas `/bucket/f1/f/` has one?

Comment: The `/bucket/f1/b` is missing the trailing slash because it is an example of a file directory whereas `/bucket/f1/f/` is an example of a folder directory.

This can be noticed in the string containing the whole structure:
`...a&b&f[]&...`

Comment: You need much more than `.split()`. You should look into parsers.

Comment: Voting to reopen because, while this question could use more explanation, something more than a casual read does show what's being asked, and it's an interesting problem.  It also already has one excellent answer.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Agreed, the question is okay-ish. The amazing answer is really the only reason to keep this post open.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: I'm hoping to find time to try an approach that I think will work, in an entirely different manner than Mulan has.  But time is tight right now.  Still, I would love to have the OP edit the question so that it doesn't take a close reading of the example to even understand.  I think there could be numerous interesting answers in very different styles.

Comment: **Thank you all** for contributing in helping me with the task. I have gave my best clarifying my question _(it was my first post)_ to improve its readability. I am already in process of in-depth studying both brilliant answers from **@Mulan and @ScottSauyet** which already have taught me a lot!

Comment: I meant to point out in my answer that -- although I use regular expressions as *part* of my solution -- you will not be able to find a single regular expression to capture this grammar.  It is not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).  More information about the levels is available in discussions of the [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).  But don't beat yourself up about not finding a regex for this: it's simply impossible!

Answer (score 3):

**background**

This is a non-trivial task but offers a great opportunity to learn about lexing and parsing. This is an essential step for all compilers of any programming language. Maybe this is your first time writing a language and interpreter. Maybe you didn't know your input string is a miniature language. Either way I hope you find this post useful. Please ask any follow-up questions if you are stuck.

**lexer**

Write `lex` to return a stream of token. We defined `open`, `close`, `and`, and `identifier` tokens.

```js
function *lex(t) {
  for (const lexeme of t.match(/([a-z0-9]+|[\[\]&])/g)) {
    s: switch (lexeme) {
      case "[":
        yield { open: true }; break s
      case "]":
        yield { close: true }; break s
      case "&":
        yield { and: true }; break s
      default:
        yield { identifier: lexeme }; break s
    }
  }
}
```

Our program input is the string of syntax in your question -

```js
const program =
  "bucket[f1[a&b&f[]&ff1[a&b]]&f2[a&b&ff1[a&b]]&f3[ff1[a]]]"

for (const v of lex(program))
  console.log(v)
```

Here's the tokens we get -

```js
{identifier: "bucket"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "f1"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "a"}
{and: true}
{identifier: "b"}
{and: true}
{identifier: "f"}
{open: true}
{close: true}
{and: true}
{identifier: "ff1"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "a"}
{and: true}
{identifier: "b"}
{close: true}
{close: true}
{and: true}
{identifier: "f2"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "a"}
{and: true}
{identifier: "b"}
{and: true}
{identifier: "ff1"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "a"}
{and: true}
{identifier: "b"}
{close: true}
{close: true}
{and: true}
{identifier: "f3"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "ff1"}
{open: true}
{identifier: "a"}
{close: true}
{close: true}
{close: true}
```

**parse**

Next we have to `parse` the tokens and give them meaning. For each token, we check which token we have and modify the returned value (`r`) accordingly -

```js
function parse(t, base = "") {
  const r = [[base]]
  let _0, _1
  for (const v of t) {
    s: switch (true) {
      case v.open:
        _0 = r.pop()
        r.push(_0)
        r.push([_0.pop()])
        break s
      case v.and:
        break s
      case v.close:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _1 = r.pop()
        _1.push(_0)
        r.push(_1)
        break s
      default:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _0.push(v.identifier)
        r.push(_0)
        break s
    }
  }
  return r[0]
}
```

We feed the output of `lex` to `parse` -

```js
console.log(parse(lex(program)))
```

And we get back a tree of our file structure -

```js
[
  "",
  [
    "bucket",
    [
      "f1",
      "a",
      "b",
      [
        "f"
      ],
      [
        "ff1",
        "a",
        "b"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "f2",
      "a",
      "b",
      [
        "ff1",
        "a",
        "b"
      ]
    ],
    [
      "f3",
      [
        "ff1",
        "a"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

**flatten**

Finally we write a `flatten` function which flattens our file tree to a list of paths. Because your program asks for trailing slash on directories without children, we make a special call out in our code -

```js
function *flatten(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      if (t.length === 1) // special case for empty dir
        yield [t[0], ""]
      else
        for (const child of t.slice(1))
          for (const path of flatten(child))
            yield [t[0], ...path]
      break
    default:
      yield [t]
  }
}
```

We take the output from `parse` and feed it to `flatten` -

```js
for (const path of flatten(parse(lex(program))))
  console.log(path.join("/"))
```

Each path is like `["", "bucket", "f1", "a"]` allowing the caller to manipulate them however they see fit. We construct a string, joining each segment with `"/"` -

```
/bucket/f1/a
/bucket/f1/b
/bucket/f1/f/
/bucket/f1/ff1/a
/bucket/f1/ff1/b
/bucket/f2/a
/bucket/f2/b
/bucket/f2/ff1/a
/bucket/f2/ff1/b
/bucket/f3/ff1/a
```

**demo**

Here's a fully functioning demo. Run it below to verify the results.

```js
function *lex(t) {
  for (const lexeme of t.match(/([a-z0-9]+|[\[\]&])/g)) {
    s: switch (lexeme) {
      case "[":
        yield { open: true }; break s
      case "]":
        yield { close: true }; break s
      case "&":
        yield { and: true }; break s
      default:
        yield { identifier: lexeme }; break s
    }
  }
}

function parse(t, base = "") {
  const r = [[base]]
  let _0, _1
  for (const v of t) {
    s: switch (true) {
      case v.open:
        _0 = r.pop()
        r.push(_0)
        r.push([_0.pop()])
        break s
      case v.and:
        break s
      case v.close:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _1 = r.pop()
        _1.push(_0)
        r.push(_1)
        break s
      default:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _0.push(v.identifier)
        r.push(_0)
        break s
    }
  }
  return r[0]
}

function *flatten(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      if (t.length === 1) // special case for empty dir
        yield [t[0], ""]
      else
        for (const child of t.slice(1))
          for (const path of flatten(child))
            yield [t[0], ...path]
      break
    default:
      yield [t]
  }
}

const program =
  "bucket[f1[a&b&f[]&ff1[a&b]]&f2[a&b&ff1[a&b]]&f3[ff1[a]]]"

for (const path of flatten(parse(lex(program))))
  console.log(path.join("/"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**changing the base path**

Did you notice `parse` accepts a second argument, `base`? You can specify a base path and it will use this when interpreting all paths in the input program. Below we call `parse` with `/usr/local` as the base -

```js
for (const path of flatten(parse(lex(program), "/usr/local")))
  console.log(path.join("/"))
```

```
/usr/local/bucket/f1/a
/usr/local/bucket/f1/b
/usr/local/bucket/f1/f/
/usr/local/bucket/f1/ff1/a
/usr/local/bucket/f1/ff1/b
/usr/local/bucket/f2/a
/usr/local/bucket/f2/b
/usr/local/bucket/f2/ff1/a
/usr/local/bucket/f2/ff1/b
/usr/local/bucket/f3/ff1/a
```

We could give a relative path too -

```js
for (const path of flatten(parse(lex(program), ".")))
  console.log(path.join("/"))
```

```
./bucket/f1/a
./bucket/f1/b
./bucket/f1/f/
./bucket/f1/ff1/a
./bucket/f1/ff1/b
./bucket/f2/a
./bucket/f2/b
./bucket/f2/ff1/a
./bucket/f2/ff1/b
./bucket/f3/ff1/a
```

**visualizing parse**

How does `parse` turn a linear list of tokens into a hierarchical tree? Below we visualize the steps taken for each token -

| token | state |
| --- | --- |
| *initial state* | [[.]] |
| {identifier: bucket} | [[., bucket]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket]] |
| {identifier: f1} | [[.], [bucket, f1]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket], [f1]] |
| {identifier: a} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a]] |
| {identifier: b} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b]] |
| {identifier: f} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, f]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b], [f]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, [f]]] |
| {identifier: ff1} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, [f], ff1]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, [f]], [ff1]] |
| {identifier: a} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, [f]], [ff1, a]] |
| {identifier: b} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, [f]], [ff1, a, b]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket], [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]]] |
| {identifier: f2} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], f2]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2]] |
| {identifier: a} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a]] |
| {identifier: b} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a, b]] |
| {identifier: ff1} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a, b, ff1]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a, b], [ff1]] |
| {identifier: a} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a, b], [ff1, a]] |
| {identifier: b} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a, b], [ff1, a, b]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]]] |
| {identifier: f3} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]], f3]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]], [f3]] |
| {identifier: ff1} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]], [f3, ff1]] |
| {open} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]], [f3], [ff1]] |
| {identifier: a} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]], [f3], [ff1, a]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]]], [f3, [ff1, a]]] |
| {close} | [[.], [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]], [f3, [ff1, a]]]] |
| {close} | [[., [bucket, [f1, a, b, [f], [ff1, a, b]], [f2, a, b, [ff1, a, b]], [f3, [ff1, a]]]]] |

**homework**

Our code above works but there are some scenarios we should address to make our program more robust.

`lex` -

- How would we handle invalid syntax?
- How would we include the character position offset for each token?

`parse` -

- Why is it safe to ignore the `&` tokens?
- How would we throw an error for unexpected `[`
- How would we throw an error for unexpected `]`
- How would we limit the maximum depth of the generated file tree?
- Where would we throw an error for tokens of invalid type?

Comment: I love the solution and the pedagogy!  See my answer for a completely different approach.

Comment: This is a well explained and detailed answer, thank you for sharing it 

Answer (score 2):

#### Another approach

There is already a fantastic answer from Mulan.  You can learn a great deal from that code, and I would suggest studying it carefully if you don't have much experience writing parsers.

But there are many ways to solve such problems, and here we examine an entirely different approach.  It can't teach as much as Mulan's answer, but there is a useful technique that might be new to some.

We'll use a different example from yours for discussion, one with longer and more familiar node names.  We want to convert this:

```js
'root[bin&export[home[user1&user2&user3]]&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]'
```

into this:

```js
[
  'root/bin',
  'root/export/home/user1',
  'root/export/home/user2',
  'root/export/home/user3',
  'root/lib',
  'root/usr/ccs',
  'root/usr/lib'
]
```

Mulan's answer wrote a parser for this mini-language.  Here we do a series of transforms that ends in

```js
'root/bin&root/export/home/user1&root/export/home/user2&root/export/home/user3&root/lib&root/usr/ccs&root/usr/lib'
```

and then simply split the result at every `'&'` to get your requested output.
The trick is that we work with one bracket-pair at a time, always one that nests no further brackets inside it.  When we've replaced that, we scan the new string for any further unnested brackets, and continue recursively until there are none to be found.  The steps will look like this:

```
'root[bin&export[home[user1&user2&user3]]&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]'
'root[bin&export[home/user1&home/user2&home/user3]&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]'
'root[bin&export/home/user1&export/home/user2&export/home/user3&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]'
'root[bin&export/home/user1&export/home/user2&export/home/user3&lib&usr/ccs&usr/lib]'
'root/bin&root/export/home/user1&root/export/home/user2&root/export/home/user3&root/lib&root/usr/ccs&root/usr/lib'
```

#### Implementation

We do this using a regular expression that captures a pair of braces with no braces inside and the preceding string that applies to them:

```
root[bin&export[home[user1&user2&user3]]&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]
               |    |_________________|`--- closing brace (']')
               |    |        `--------+---- parts (['user1', 'user2', 'user3'])
               |    |`----------------+---- opening brace ('[')
               |____|                 |
               |  `-------------------+---- prefix ('home')
               |______________________|
                          `---------------- full match ('[home[user1&user2&user3]')
```

Then we replace the string we've found, joining each of the words inside the brackets with the prefix and a `'/'` to yield `'home/user1&home/user2&home/user3'`.  Then we recur on this new value, ending when there is no match.

The code looks like this:

```js
const brackets = /([^\[\]\&]+)\[([^\[\]]*)\]/

const expand = (s) =>
  brackets .test (s)
    ? expand (s .replace (
        brackets, 
        (_, prefix, ps) => ps .split ('&') .map (p => prefix + '/' + p) .join ('&')
      ))
    : s

const parse = (s) =>
  expand (s) .split ('&') 


console .log (parse ('root[bin&export[home[user1&user2&user3]]&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]'))
console .log (parse ('bucket[f1[ab&f[]&ff1[a&b]]&f2[a&b&ff1[a&b]]&f3[ff1[a]]]'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

#### Notes

- Our running example does not demonstrate the empty folders, but we show the example from the question to demonstrate that it does as required.  No special processing turns out to be necessary for this.
- This is recursive, and could run into recursion-depth problems if you're using this for large inputs.  It would be a simple, mechanical process to turn this into a `while` loop.
- Regular expressions are very powerful, but often difficult to understand.  I personally find them quite worth the effort.  You can find an explanation of this regex [on Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DExjjQ/1).  But when my first attempt at a regex solution failed, I wrote [a mostly-equivalent solution](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/56) without the regex.  It might be instructive to compare that imperative code with this version.  After writing it, I was able to recognize what I'd done wrong with my initial regular expression and write this cleaner version.
- We do nothing here to capture bad input.  It shouldn't be hard to do so here, but we leave it as an exercise for the reader.  (*Hint*: it seems possible that any bad input would necessarily leave some brackets behind after the expansion.)

### Update

Mulan (in comment below) noted that by double-calling the regular expression, we are adding inefficiencies.  Of course that's right, although I haven't actually tested.  We can do this with a single `exec` call with code like this:

```js
const expand = (s, match = /([^\[\]\&]+)\[([^\[\]]*)\]/ .exec (s)) => match  
  ? expand (
      s .slice (0, match .index) 
      + match [2] .split ('&') .map (p => match [1] + '/' + p) .join ('&') 
      + s .slice (match .index + match [0] .length))
  : s

const parse = (s) =>
  expand (s) .split ('&') 


console .log (parse ('root[bin&export[home[user1&user2&user3]]&lib&usr[ccs&lib]]'))
console .log (parse ('bucket[f1[ab&f[]&ff1[a&b]]&f2[a&b&ff1[a&b]]&f3[ff1[a]]]'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I have mixed feelings.  Unless and until I test the relative performance, and find that this variant is substantially faster, it loses a lot to my mind due to having to deal with the output of `exec` and due to the index manipulations.  At the very least, though, this is a very worthy contender.

Comment: terrific work with a super thin implementation. i was originally thinking of `re.exec` in a loop to take advantage of stateful regex, but opted for lex/parse because of the added challenge. that, and i've come to understand the regex engine is not so efficient. on that note, you could cut your execution time in half (approx) by removing `brackets.test` in your condition, which invokes the regex engine twice as much as you need. you could use mutual recursion to keep the elegance you have attained. if i find time later today, i'll try to measure the actual difference.

Comment: @Mulan: I added an update to replace the regex `test` and `replace` calls with a single `exec` and some index manipulations.  I am much less happy with the code, though.  The index manipulations and the very format of the `exec` results are an anathema to me.  At some point I'll try to run a benchmark to help me decide whether the speed improvement is worth the code complexity.  Did you have something else in mind?  I don't see any good way to drop `test` without substituting `exec` for `replace`; `test` helps distinguish the base case from the recursive one.

Comment: Confirmed.  [A simple benchmark](https://jsbench.me/u0l5tws3k4/1) says that the new one is about 50% faster.  We could probably further speed things up by replacing the recursion with a `while` loop.

Comment: i increased the problem size a bit in the setup. [surprisingly](https://jsbench.me/a3l5txr97u/1) the `while` loop is no faster than your recursive implementations and the mutual recursive implementation i was describing. and i did not expect the one-off regexp and generators used in lex-parse-flatten to be _that_ much faster. now i'm wondering what difference a few optimizations could look like there...

Comment: Ahh, that mutually recursive version is beautiful!  I agree.  I was expecting the true parser to be faster, but thought it would only become significantly so with much larger inputs than your (nicely-constructed!) input.  In any case, kudos on your excellent answer and the analysis of this one.  (I do have to say, though, that `while ((match = re.exec(s)) !== null)` reminds me of bad old Java days!  ;-) )

Comment: right?! i absolutely despise the syntax required to make the `while` loop run... as much as i love generators, it's [8x faster](https://jsbench.me/a3l5txr97u/2) without them 'v_v.

Comment: @Mulan: While looking at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73938866/), I found a version that is -- while still only half the speed of your lexer-parser -- is [substantially faster](https://jsbench.me/bwl8xeb7y8/1) than the above, still with fairly simple code.  But when I tried to extend it to cover more ground... it grew quite shaky.