# Javascript - how to generate all possible strings from a template?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a string template that looks like this `A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]`. Each set of `[X,Y,Z]` means either X, or Y, or Z, so `A[B[C,D],E]` would expand to `ABC`, `ABD`, `AE`. I'm trying to generate a list of all possible strings that match such a template.

I've tried the resursive approach like this:

```
const x = 'A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]';

function expand(template) {
    const matches = template.match(/^(.*)\[([^\[\]]+)\](.*)$/);
    if (! matches) return template;
    const expanded = matches[2].split(',').map(x => `${matches[1]}${x}${matches[3]}`);
    return expanded.flatMap(option => expand(option));
}

console.log(expand(x));
```

But my resulting array is 768 elements long, where only 11 elements are unique. For a small template string this is fine - I can remove duplicates. But on a template of 500 characters it doesn't ever stop running.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Start with the outermost expansion, not the innermost one.

Comment: The whole point of starting with the innermost one is that regular expressions for balanced brackets are a nightmare (you can't do them with traditional REs at all). In order to start with the outer one you have to start with properly parsing the whole thing.

Comment: @btilly Well yes, that's the idea. You should parse it into an abstract representation of the template instead of twiddling with string replacements.

Comment: @Bergi Parsing tends to be more code, and relatively slow code. Where twiddling works, it is often much faster. But tops out.  Still worth trying though.

Comment: @btilly I don't see why parsing code would be slow.

Comment: @Bergi Because building up and tearing down data structures in high level languages is slower than string manipulation.

Comment: `Each set of [X,Y,Z] means either X, or Y, or Z, so A[B[C,D],E] would expand to ABC, ABD, AE.`  Based on the rule, why isn't the result of the example expansion A, AB, ABC, ABD, AE?

Comment: @Trentium Because the second part of a concatenation isn't optional. You'd writ `A[,B[,C,D],E]` for that.

Comment: @Bergi, where the OP states `X, or Y, or Z`, my interpretation is that `or Y, or Z` implies optionality.  Therefore, 'A' should be one of the options, no?  Or maybe the rule is ambiguous...

Comment: @Trentium "X or Y or Z" does not mean "X or Y or Z or nothing". The whole set, and thereby all options, are preceded by "A".

Comment: @Bergi it seems by that logic that `AE` should then not be part of the result set, as `Z` is then `nothing`, no?  And if `Z` can be nothing, then why not `Y`?  So my interpretation is that the rule logic is ambiguous...

Comment: @Trentium I don't see any ambiguity, but you seem to ignore the nesting. `A[B[C,D],E]` expands to `A[BC,BD,E]` which expands to `ABC,ABD,AE`. `AE` is in the result set or `A[…,E]` regardless of what `…` is.

Comment: @Henlo, any reason why you don't bring clarification after all these comments? Is it allowed to have a letter after `]`, like `A[B,C]D`? Is it allowed to have `[` after `]`, Like `[A,B][C,D]`? Please clarify....

Comment: @trincot, sorry, I was asleep. Yeah, @Bergi is correct, `[A,B]`, means "A" or "B", so `A[A,B]` -> `AA`, `AB`.

Comment: @trincot, as for the letter - yes `A[B,C]D` is valid. `[A,B][C,D]` is also valid.

Comment: [Another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73023315) should give you some good techniques.

Comment: Take a look at object-fields. Basically answers exactly your question (disclaimer I'm the author)

Comment: @vincent: link, please?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Here you go https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of this code is a straight-forward top-down recursive descent parser for templates. It suffers from a bit of code repetition, which I might fix at some point, having to do with the similarity between the top-level string  and segments within bracketed expressions (what's called a segment is the part between commas).

It doesn't build an AST, which is possibly another weakness, but it seemed a bit overkill to build a tree; it just constructs lists of alternatives as it goes. It puts together the alternatives from a segment by computing the Cartesian product of the concatenated segments, and then it accumulates the segments in a bracketed list in order to return the complete list of alternatives to the caller.

Please note that the code makes no attempt to deduplicate the template; if you use a template like `[A,AB][BA,A]`, you'll find `ABA` twice in the output. This could be fixed rather crudely by accumulating the results into a set rather than an array, or by turning the template into something like a trie (possibly a good reason to create an AST during the parse) and then generating the alternatives by walking the trie.

```js
function cartesianProduct(alts1, alts2) {
  rv = []
  for (const first of alts1)
    for (const second of alts2)
      rv.push(first + second)
  return rv
}

// This is really just a special case of cartesianProduct,
// so it's totally unnecessary.
function appendSuffix(alts, suffix) {
  for (let idx = 0; idx < alts.length; ++idx)
    alts[idx] += suffix
}

function expandTemplate(tmpl) {
  // The 'y' flag effectively makes a JS regular expression
  // into a tokenizer; the regexp itself keeps track of the
  // scan cursor, but it's up to the caller to ensure that the
  // same scanned string is supplied for every call. It's a bit
  // fragile, but it's very effective for simple cases. 
  //   Each token alternative has its own capture; in this case,
  // all of the metacharacters (comma and brackets) are in the
  // second capture as single characters, while the uninterpreted
  // strings are returned in the first capture. That makes it
  // fairly easy to tell what the token type is.
  const rgx = /([^\[\],]+)|(.)/y

  // Internal function parses a single bracketed expression, and
  // returns all the alternatives defined (working recursively).
  // It's invoked when a [ is encountered, and it continues until
  // it finds the matching ], which it discards.
  function helper() {
    let rv = []
    let segment = ['']
    let match = null;
    while (match = rgx.exec(tmpl)) {
      if (match[1])
        appendSuffix(segment, match[1])
      else { 
        switch (match[2]) {
          case '[':
            segment = cartesianProduct(segment, helper())
            break
          case ',':
            rv.push(segment)
            segment = ['']
            break
          case ']':
            rv.push(segment)
            return [].concat(...rv)
        }
      }
    }
    throw 'Unexpected end of template; unmatched "["'
  }
  
  // The main function starts here. It's essentially the
  // same as the helper, except that it only parses a single
  // segment and expects to return when it reaches the end of
  // the input.
  let segment = ['']
  let match = null;
  while (match = rgx.exec(tmpl)) {
    if (match[1])
      appendSuffix(segment, match[1])
    else {
      switch (match[2]) {
        case '[':
          segment = cartesianProduct(segment, helper())
          break
        case ',':
          throw '"," used in top-level template'
        case ']':
          throw 'Unexpected "]"'
      }
    }
  }
  return segment
}


const x = 'A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]';
console.log(expandTemplate(x));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is just like expanding algebraic expressions that has `*` , `+`  and `()`. Brilliant

Comment: This is very nice, but it still can produce duplicate strings if there are multiple paths through the template that give the same string.

Comment: @btilly: that's correct; I should have mentioned that. It could be improved by using a set rather than an array to collect the strings, although I suppose that the optimal solution is to turn the template into a DFA (or even a trie) and then enumerate the possible outcomes. That was too much to write at 1 a.m.

Answer (score 2):

### Handling a simplified case

We can do this in a technique very similar to your own with only one simple difference.  When we find the innermost square-bracket delineated element, instead of flat-mapping over that section, we replace it with its comma-separated expansion, then recur.  If there are no more bracket-pairs, we split on the commas and return the resulting array.  The number of recursive calls will be based on the number of bracket-pairs, and the recursion-depth with be limited by the most deeply-nested pair.  The process would look like this:

```js
"A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,NO,NP]]]]]]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,HM,HNO,HNP]]]]]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,FG,FHM,FHNO,FHNP]]]]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,DE,DFG,DFHM,DFHNO,DFHNP]]]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,BC,BDE,BDFG,BDFHM,BDFHNO,BDFHNP]]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,D[E,F,GA,GBC,GBDE,GBDFG,GBDFHM,GBDFHNO,GBDFHNP]],MMMMM]"
"A[B[C,DE,DF,DGA,DGBC,DGBDE,DGBDFG,DGBDFHM,DGBDFHNO,DGBDFHNP],MMMMM]"
"A[BC,BDE,BDF,BDGA,BDGBC,BDGBDE,BDGBDFG,BDGBDFHM,BDGBDFHNO,BDGBDFHNP,MMMMM]"
"ABC,ABDE,ABDF,ABDGA,ABDGBC,ABDGBDE,ABDGBDFG,ABDGBDFHM,ABDGBDFHNO,ABDGBDFHNP,AMMMMM"
```

Here is my version:

```js
const expand = (s) => s .indexOf ('[') < 0
  ? s .split (',')
  : expand (s .replace (
      /([^\[\]\,]+)\[([^\[\]]*)\]/,
      (_, p, gs) => gs .split (',') .map (g => p + g)
    ))

console .log (expand ('A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This is based very much on [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73045542) to a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73023315), although cleaned up and simplified (and in the process much sped up).  There are more more efficient ways of doing this, and [Mulan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027554) to that question demonstrates an excellent one; furthermore, like many of Mulan's answer, it's a great learning resource.  But if this is efficient enough for your own needs, it's quite simple code.  Also, as noted, it's quite close to your own attempt.

**But**, this only handles a limited subset of possible such bracketed inputs.  It assumes that any bracket-set is composed of a prefix, an open bracket, a comma-separated list of values (possibly including other bracket-sets), and a close bracket, that all commas are inside bracket sets, and probably some other conditions.

If doesn't handle something like `[A,B][C,D]`, which we might want to turn into `['AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD']` or `[A,B],[C,D]`, which would presumably lead to `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

### More sophisticated

If that's what you are looking for, then this should be fine.  I wanted to go further, and I came up with a more sophisticated version, that handles many more cases:

```js
const cartesian = ([xs, ...xss]) =>
  xs == undefined ? [[]] : xs .flatMap (x => cartesian (xss) .map (ys => [x, ...ys]))

const expand = (s) =>
  s .indexOf ('[') < 0                  // 'A,B,C'         => return ['A', 'B', 'C']
    ? s .split (',')
  : s .match (/^\[([^\[\]]*)\]$/)       // '[A,B,C]'       => return ['A', 'B', 'C']
    ? s .slice (1, -1) .split (',')
  : expand (s .replace (                // '[[A,B,C]]`     => '[A,B,C]' 
      /\[\[([^\[\]]*)\]\]/,             
      (_, p) =>`[` + p + `]`
    ) .replace (                        // '[A,[B,C]]'     => '[A,B,C]'  or
      /([^\[\]\,]+)(,?)\[([^\[\]]*)\]/, // '[A[B,C]]'      => '[AB,AC]'   
      (_, p, c, gs) => c 
        ? p + ',' + gs 
        : `[` + gs .split (',') .map (g => p + g) .join (',') + `]`
    ) .replace (                        // '[[A,B],C]'     => '[A,B,C]'  or
      /\[([^\[\]]*)\](,?)([^\[\]\,]+)/, // '[[A,B]C]'      => '[AC,BC]'
      (_, gs, c, p) => c 
        ? gs + ',' + p 
        : `[` + gs .split (',') .map (g => g + p) .join (',') + `]`
    ) .replace (
      /\[([^\[\]]*)\]\[([^\[\]]*)\]/,   // '[[A,B][C,D]]'  => '[AC,AD,BC,BD]'
      (_, xs, ys) => `[` + cartesian ([xs .split (','), ys .split (',')]) 
                           .map (ss => ss .join ('')) .join(',')        + `]`
    ) .replace (
      /\[([^\[\]]+)\],\[([^\[\]]+)\]/,  // '[[A,B],[C,D]'  => '[A,B,C,D]'
      (_, xs, ys) => `[` + xs + `,` + ys + `]`
    ))

const testCases = [
  'A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]',
  '[B,C][D,E]',
  'A[B,C,D]X[D,E,F]G',
  '[A,[B,C]]',
  'A[B,C]X[D,E,F]G',
  '[X[A,B]Y,[C,D,E]Z]',
  '[[A,B],[C,D],[E,F]]',
  '[[[A,B]]]',
]

testCases .forEach (t => console .log (t + ': ', expand (t)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

The various regex replaces have comments with an example or two, and note that although they each run on the result of the others, the main point is that they are wrapped in recursive calls so that we do the same thing as the above, working from the inside out trying to resolve smaller things first.

We use a `cartesian` helper I had laying around; we could probably use a simpler one, since we are working on only two arrays at a time, but this one still works.

This is not code to love.  It's probably not even code to like.  I would probably use a full-fledged lexer/parser before this.  But it's interesting nonetheless.

Comment: thanks for linking my work and drawing my attention to this question. i'll take a shot at the expanded cases when i find the time. am i missing it or did the OP state where `[AB][CD]` is valid and how it should be evaluated?

Comment: @Mulan: It was [embedded in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73938866/#comment130564020_73938866) the long comments section.  Although I was mostly interested in the simplest version of this answer in relation to the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73023315), I got stubborn enough to see it through to a (fairly ugly) conclusion.  I knew we could write it as a parser, and hoped you might chime in with your own version. (Thanks!)  My test cases show some of the additional variants that didn't work in successive versions.  I may still be missing some... which makes this sub-optimal.

Answer (score 2):

**one tiny regexp**

This is a non-trivial question and this answer hopes to provide a real-world solution to the problem. I used the lexer/parser from [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027554/633183) with minimal modification.

```js
const program =
  "A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]"

for (const path of flatten(parse(lex(program))))
  console.log(path.join(""))
```

```
ABC
ABDE
ABDF
ABDGA
ABDGBC
ABDGBDE
ABDGBDFG
ABDGBDFHM
ABDGBDFHNO
ABDGBDFHNP
AMMMMM
```

**lex**

The lexer in this program differs in a minor way. We add support for uppercase strings and use `,` instead of `&` -

```js
function *lex(t) {
  for (const lexeme of t.match(/([a-z0-9]+|[\[\],])/gi)) {
    s: switch (lexeme) {
      case "[":
        yield { open: true }; break s
      case "]":
        yield { close: true }; break s
      case ",":
        yield { and: true }; break s
      default:
        yield { identifier: lexeme }; break s
    }
  }
}
```

**parse**

The parser is the same -

```js
function parse(t, base = "") {
  const r = [[base]]
  let _0, _1
  for (const v of t) {
    s: switch (true) {
      case v.open:
        _0 = r.pop()
        r.push(_0)
        r.push([_0.pop()])
        break s
      case v.and:
        break s
      case v.close:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _1 = r.pop()
        _1.push(_0)
        r.push(_1)
        break s
      default:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _0.push(v.identifier)
        r.push(_0)
        break s
    }
  }
  return r[0]
}
```

**flatten**

Flattening is the same -

```js
function *flatten(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      for (const child of t.slice(1))
        for (const path of flatten(child))
          yield [t[0], ...path]
      break
    default:
      yield [t]
  }
}
```

<kbd>Run</kbd> the program below to verify the result in your own browser -

```js
function *lex(t) {
  for (const lexeme of t.match(/([a-z]+|[\[\],])/gi)) {
    s: switch (lexeme) {
      case "[":
        yield { open: true }; break s
      case "]":
        yield { close: true }; break s
      case ",":
        yield { and: true }; break s
      default:
        yield { identifier: lexeme }; break s
    }
  }
}

function parse(t, base = "") {
  const r = [[base]]
  let _0, _1
  for (const v of t) {
    s: switch (true) {
      case v.open:
        _0 = r.pop()
        r.push(_0)
        r.push([_0.pop()])
        break s
      case v.and:
        break s
      case v.close:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _1 = r.pop()
        _1.push(_0)
        r.push(_1)
        break s
      default:
        _0 = r.pop()
        _0.push(v.identifier)
        r.push(_0)
        break s
    }
  }
  return r[0]
}

function *flatten(t) {
  switch (t?.constructor) {
    case Array:
      for (const child of t.slice(1))
        for (const path of flatten(child))
          yield [t[0], ...path]
      break
    default:
      yield [t]
  }
}

const program =
  "A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]"

for (const path of flatten(parse(lex(program))))
  console.log(path.join(""))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

**keep it simple**

Above `lex` was written as a generator to yield object-based tokens. This is a choice I made to make certain aspects of parsing easier, but it is not a requirement. When you write your own `lex` and `parse`, you can make these choices for yourself.

Below we write a true 1-line lexer. It works by using a regexp *capture group* supplied to `.split`, something many JavaScript developers are unaware of. The result is an array of string-based tokens that are ready for parsing -

```js
const program =
  "A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]"
  
const lex = p =>
  p.split(/([\[\],])/)
  
console.log(lex(program))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is really hacky <del>but it just might</del> and doesn't work. The idea is doing simple search and replace to make the input look like a json. Then parse it and print the paths of the leaves of that tree.

```js
const x = 'A[B[C,D[E,F,G[A,B[C,D[E,F[G,H[M,N[O,P]]]]]]]],MMMMM]';

var str = x;
str = str.replace(/\[/g, ": {")
str = str.replace(/\]/g, "}")
str = str.replace(/,/g, ": null, ")
str = str.replace(/\}: null,/g, "}, ")
str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])\}/g, "$1: null}")
str = str.replace(/([a-zA-Z])$/g, "$1: null")
str = str.replace(/null/g, "{}")
// console.log(str)
var tree
eval("tree  = {" + str + "}")
//console.log(tree)
console.log(getPath(tree))

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44759609/3807365
function getPath(object) {
  function iter(o, p) {
    var keys = Object.keys(o);
    if (keys.length) {
      return keys.forEach(function(k) {
        iter(o[k], p + k);
      });
    }
    result.push(p);
  }

  var result = [];
  iter(object, []);
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This only works for a tree structure though, not for `[A,B][C,D]` or `A[B,C]D`